# Install Google Cloud Vision on Ubuntu with Google Cloud Python SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

On Ubuntu 14.04, I've successfully installed the Python SDK following this: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get

Also, I am able to deploy the app to Google App Engine, using the `appcfg.py` script.

I do have a configuration file where I declare the `vendors` directory and all third party libraries are installed there.

Everything works, except when I try to import Google Cloud Vision:

> File "/home/vagrant/source/web/handlers/posts.py", line 8, in
>   
>       from google.cloud import vision   File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py",
>   line 1149, in load_module
>       raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) ImportError: No module named google.cloud.vision

I have installed Google Cloud Vision both with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade -t lib google-cloud-vision
```

None of them work.

How do I install locally? As a third party or globally? How will it work on Google when I deploy?

Answer (score 0):

On the SDK's GitHub page it's [stated](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) that the Python idiomatic library for Google Cloud can't be run on App Engine for Python 2:

> Heads up! These libraries are supported on App Engine standard's Python 3 runtime but are not supported on App Engine's Python 2 runtime.